# Intel SSD not recognized internally in a Mac Mini 2012 but works well in an external Thunderbolt enclosure

Tags: macos, mac, sata

I recently got a couple of SSDs ([Samsung 850 EVO](http://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/product/consumer/850evo.html), [Intel X25-E Extreme](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/solid-state-drives/legacy-consumer-ssds/intel-ssd-x25-e-series.html) 64GB) for my Mac Mini 2012, and bought a second SATA cable from OWC (Other World Computing). I removed the original SATA II HDD. Here's what happened:

The Samsung SSD works great with either the original Apple or the new OWC cable, on either SATA port. The Intel SSD works great in an external Thunderbolt enclosure, but I can not get it to be recognized when connected internally, with either cable, on either SATA port.

I'm at a complete loss to explain this behavior. Can anyone help?

Comment: @JakeGould yeah, I did that in parallel, thanks. But if this were really so common I'd expect google to have found me some answers already.